# Can the minimum spanning tree have different values for max weighted edge

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Can a complete graph with a sufficiently large number of vertices have different values for an edge with a maximum weight in different implementations? or can the maximum weighted edge of MST have different values when applying different algorithms?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For any simple undirected graph and any minimum spanning tree (MST) of that graph,

- the weight of the maximum weighted edge would be the same
- the endpoints of the maximum weighted edge need not be same

Any set of $n-1$ edges that connect all $n$ vertices of a graph with minimum weight, forms a MST of that graph.
Hence, the MST need not be unique and endpoints of maximum weighted edge could be different.

However, the weight of the maximum weighted edge should be the same since an MST is formed by greedily taking minimum weighted edges.